# formatting data in new structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've at the moment 1 array with labels and 2 objects with keys and values.
With this data i want to format a new array with object.

Example:

```
const years = ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
const left = {5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 22};
const right = {6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 22, 9: 1};

//Output should be
const newArr = [
    {
        label: 5 year,
        left: 2,
        right: null,
    },
    {
        label: 6 year,
        left: 1,
        right: 1,
    },
    {
        label: 7 year,
        left: 22,
        right: 1,
    },
    {
        label: 8 year,
        left: null,
        right: 22,
    },
    {
        label: 9 year,
        left: null,
        right: 1,
    },
]
```

if one of the object doesn't have the year(key) in object this value is null.

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: You should try to solve the problem and post your tried out solution too instead of directly jumping to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map`

```
var replaceFn = ( obj, key ) => !obj.hasOwnProperty( key ) ? null : obj[ key ]; 

var output = years.map( s => ({ 
         label : s + " years", 
         left : replaceFn( left, s ), 
         right : replaceFn( right, s ) 
}));
```

**Demo**

```js
var years = ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var left = {5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 22, 8: undefined};
var right = {6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 22, 9: 1};

console.log( left.hasOwnProperty( 8 ) );

var replaceFn = ( obj, key ) => !obj.hasOwnProperty( key ) ? null : obj[ key ]; 

var output = years.map( s => ({ 
         label : s + " years", 
         left : replaceFn( left, s ), 
         right : replaceFn( right, s ) 
}));

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Nice solution, might be a little complicated for OP, but nevertheless very neat.

Comment: @user184994 yes, had done that for the demo, but now corrected in the main answer as well.

Comment: Sure @tushar, I will fix this as well.

Comment: @Baruch Why do you think that using `map` is more complicated than `forEach` and `push`?

Comment: @RalphJanssen Glad it worked for you. I have made some changes to handle the scenario where a *falsey* value is given to object's key to properly handle the criteria of *if one of the object doesn't have the year(key) in object this value is null.*.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the years array and dynamically get the value from the other two objects:

```
const years = ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
const left = {5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 22};
const right = {6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 22, 9: 1};

const newArr = [];

years.forEach(year => {
  newArr.push({
    label: `${year} year(s)`,
    right: right[year] || null,
    left: left[year] || null,
  })
});
```

example: https://repl.it/repls/StingyIrritatingCrayfish

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the key is in the objects ([`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)) and take the value, otherwise take `null`.

```js
var years = ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
    left = { 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 22 },
    right = { 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 22, 9: 1 },
    result = years.map(k => ({
        label: k + ' year',
        left: k in left ? left[k] : null,
        right: k in right ? right[k] : null
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: [if (key in object) or if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)](//stackoverflow.com/q/13632999)